# Start a new process without blocking the terminal

Tags: command-line, gedit, process

Is it possible to do this? For example if I run "`gedit tifatul.txt`" via the command line, my terminal becomes blocked and I can't enter other command in this terminal before I quit gedit. Can I start a program (like gedit) without blocking the terminal? In windows I think this can be done like "`start notepad tifatul.txt`"

Comment: What do you mean by blocked.

Comment: @PedroDiniz meaning I can't type another command to the terminal while gedit is running. If you have windows, try the difference between running `notepad` (blocked) and `start notepad` (not blocked)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Just add `&` at the end of the command. This makes the new process to run in background and you can continue using your terminal. For example: `gedit new_file.txt &`

Comment: By the way, do you know any documentation regarding this behaviour? Is it only for gedit?

Comment: This feature of background process is provided by the shell, so it is not working only for gedit but for any command you run on shell.

Comment: yeah, thanks for the answer. I was gonna accept but the system requires me to wait another couple of minutes

Comment: Accepted and upvoted :) By the way what is this feature called?

Comment: This feature is called running processes in background or running background processes.

Comment: Any way to spawn a new process in a way that it can't output to the console? For instance, `nautilus . &` keeps sending various warnings and outputs to the console. **EDIT:** `exec nautilus . &` seems to work. **EDIT 2:** No it doesn't. :( **EDIT 3:** Oh it does. You just hit `Ctrl+C` to get out of the infinite block, but the program doesn't get killed.

Comment: But this doesn't work in git hook

Comment: Please add the warning of what happens if you close your terminal.

Answer (score 26):

I would like to recommend you `nohup gedit filename &`. Simply `gedit filename &`, you're bearing the risk to accidentally close the terminal and lose your edit. If you don't like `nohup.out` being created each time, just redirect the output:

```
nohup gedit filename > /dev/null &
```

Comment: What about this format nohup gedit filename > /dev/null 2>&1 &
I saw it recommended in an archive from 2009 https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1345506.html